# Assigning matrix name as plot title in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm producing a series of plots in R Studio with only the data source changing between them. Instead of manually editing the title of each, I'd like to automatically assign the plot title to be the name of the data source (a matrix). I'm struggling to conceptualize the logic flow here though. 
Overly simplified code example:

```
a<-matrix(1:10, ncol = 10,nrow=10)
b<-matrix(10:20,ncol=10,nrow=10)
plot(a) 
   mtext(side=3, "a") #I'm using mtext instead of main because the plotting function I use doesn't support 'main'
plot(b)
   mtext(side=3, "b")
```

So in this example, I'd want the main title of the first plot to be "a", and the second to be "b"; however, the way it's written now I need to manually adjust `mtext(side=3,"X"`. I'd like to have the mtext statement read the matrix name and use that. I'll admit, this is a bit beyond my abilities. Any assistance is appreciate!

My actual code is not going to be reproducible due to a lack of source data, but as requested in comments, it follows:

```
source<-n20DO1 #source data used to generate comm
comm<-bn20DO1  #actual data being used, this is the one with the title

Low<-count(source$DObin==1)[2,2]
Low<-if(is.na(Low)) {Low <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==1)[2,2]}
Mod<-count(source$DObin==2)[2,2]
Mod<-if(is.na(Mod)) {Mod <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==2)[2,2]}
High<-count(source$DObin==3)[2,2]
High<-if(is.na(High)) {High <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==3)[2,2]}
LMH <- matrix(c(Low, Mod, High),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(LMH) <- c("Count")
rownames(LMH) <- c("Low","Mod", "High")
LMH <- as.table(LMH)
LMH

tries=20
NMDS20=metaMDS(comm, k=2,try=tries)
treat=c(rep("Low",Low),rep("Moderate",Mod),rep("High",High))
ordiplot(NMDS20,type="n",choices=c(1,2),xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
         xlab="nmds1",ylab="nmds2")
colors=c(rep("black",Low),rep("yellow",Mod),rep("red",High))
for(i in unique(treat)) {
        ordihull(NMDS20$point[grep(i,treat),],draw="polygon",
                 groups=treat[treat==i],col=colors[grep(i,treat)],label=F) } 
orditorp(NMDS20,col=c(rep("black",Low),rep("yellow",Mod),rep("red",High)),
         air=0.01,cex=1.25,display="species")
mtext(side=3,"20 DO") #This is where I want the title adjusted
mtext(side=1,"Stress =" )
mtext(side=1,padj=1, round(NMDS20$stress, 4))
```

Comment: Related: [Pass variable name to plotting function title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666151/pass-variable-name-to-plotting-function-title)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple approach with writing a custom function using `substitute`:

```
my_mtext <- function(mat)mtext(side = 3, text = substitute(mat))
plot(a)
my_mtext(a)
```

[image]
I'll admit that `help(substitute)` isn't the most helpful thing in the world:

> Substitute returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression `expr`

This means that substitute returns the unevaluated expression for `mat` rather than the matrix itself. Therefore you can use the symbol as text in your plot.

As a side note, the **Details** from help kind of are helpful:

> The typical use of substitute is to create informative labels for data sets and plots.

**Edit**
Now with your new code:

```
makePlot <- function(source, comm) {
Low<-count(source$DObin==1)[2,2]
Low<-if(is.na(Low)) {Low <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==1)[2,2]}
Mod<-count(source$DObin==2)[2,2]
Mod<-if(is.na(Mod)) {Mod <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==2)[2,2]}
High<-count(source$DObin==3)[2,2]
High<-if(is.na(High)) {High <- 0} else {count(source$DObin==3)[2,2]}
LMH <- matrix(c(Low, Mod, High),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(LMH) <- c("Count")
rownames(LMH) <- c("Low","Mod", "High")
LMH <- as.table(LMH)
LMH

tries=20
NMDS20=metaMDS(comm, k=2,try=tries)
treat=c(rep("Low",Low),rep("Moderate",Mod),rep("High",High))
ordiplot(NMDS20,type="n",choices=c(1,2),xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
         xlab="nmds1",ylab="nmds2")
colors=c(rep("black",Low),rep("yellow",Mod),rep("red",High))
for(i in unique(treat)) {
        ordihull(NMDS20$point[grep(i,treat),],draw="polygon",
                 groups=treat[treat==i],col=colors[grep(i,treat)],label=F) } 
orditorp(NMDS20,col=c(rep("black",Low),rep("yellow",Mod),rep("red",High)),
         air=0.01,cex=1.25,display="species")
mtext(side=3, paste("20 DO", substitute(comm)) #This is where I want the title adjusted
mtext(side=1,"Stress =" )
mtext(side=1,padj=1, round(NMDS20$stress, 4))
}

makePlot(source = n20DO1, comm = bn20DO1)
```

Comment: Very simple and to-the-point, nice. How about: `function(mat, ..., main) { if (missing(main)) main <- substitute(mat); plot(mat, ..., main = main); }` is a little more general and passes arbitrary arguments to the next appropriate plot method (even if not a matrix).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I'm reading this right, this answer applies to directly plotting within the function using 'main', correct? How might I adapt it to using mtext? In my actual code I'm using ordiplot. Putting my ordiplot in this plot_matrix() returns the error "'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'".

Comment: I'm still getting a weird result, but that may be a function of my own ignorance more than anything. I appreciate your time and will keep poking at it. I think you've given me the core of what I need.

Comment: @IanCampbell, sry, delayed response ... nahhh, it's just an option to throw at yours, feel free to use or ignore. Thanks.

Comment: So the way I implemented your edit was to put that code at the top, then replaced mtext(side=3, "20 DO") with my_mytext(comm). When I do that, I get the title as comm. I think I'm close. If you look at the top, comm is a data matrix reading something new in (this and source are all I change between plots). I want it to paste the title of the matrix saved as comm. SUPER close. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @IanCampbell again, we're so close and I'm sorry to be a bother. That still produces a main title as "20 DO comm" but what I'd like to get is "20 DO bn20DO1 " as "bn20DO1  "is the title of the matrix being read in to comm.

Comment: I see, I should have been able to figure that out. That's more tricky. How about making the whole process a custom function and then using arguments for the `source` and `comm` like in my edit?

Comment: that looks like the trick. I don't have time atm to run it but will try in the am. thank you.

Comment: @IanCampbell your makePlot function worked perfectly, and cut out several hundred lines of code for me. Much obliged!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to place them in a list:

```
data = list(
a=matrix(1:10, ncol = 10,nrow=10),
b=matrix(11:20,ncol=10,nrow=10)
)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for(i in names(data)){
plot(data[[i]],xlab="x",ylab="y")
mtext(side=3, i)
}
```

[image]